# Why mapper returns null?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping, mapstruct

Question: Why mapper returns null ?

Can anybody explain me why my mapper(mapstruct) returns null ? When I implement my own mapper then its ok.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class CouponServiceTestSuite {
    @InjectMocks
    private CouponService couponService;
    @Mock
    private CouponRepository couponRepository;
    @Spy
    private CouponDto couponDto;
    @Spy
    private CouponMapper couponMapper;


    @Test
    public void testMapper() {
        Coupon coupon = createCoupon();
        CouponDto couponDto = couponMapper.mapToCouponDto(coupon);

        System.out.println(couponDto); // RETURN NULL
    }
```

```
@Component
@Mapper
public interface CouponMapper {

    Coupon mapToCoupon(CouponDto couponDto);

    CouponDto mapToCouponDto(Coupon coupon);

    default List<CouponDto> mapToCouponDtoList(List<Coupon> couponList) {
        if (couponList == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(couponList).stream()
                .map(this::mapToCouponDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

https://github.com/kenez92/BetWinner2/blob/CouponServiceTestSuite/src/test/java/com/kenez92/betwinner/service/CouponServiceTestSuite.java

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you getting null return or NullPointer?

Comment: This returns null. Should return mapped object but this object is always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns null because you have a `@Spy`. This means that Mockito will wrap the implementation in an instance of its own and then invoke the methods (if it is null it will return null for the methods).

You should probably use `@SpyBean` and `@MockBean` from Spring Boot if you want to have the beans which are available in your application context spied or mocked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
@Spy
private CouponMapper couponMapper;
```

use-

```
private final CouponMapper couponMapper= Mappers.getMapper(CouponMapper.class);
```

using Mappers.getMapper will solve this issue, I tried using @SpyBean and @MockBean did not worked for me.